# AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer() return NULL for all controls in a Panel

Tags: c#, wpf, null, adornerlayer

I'm facing the fact that i cannot understand Well how AdornerLayer is added for UIElements.

I have such a situation:

I have a WPF Form which is built with 3 controls: 
A **Grid** on which are 1 **Button** and 1 **TextBox**. 
[image]

In my System, when I click to open this Form, all 3 elements have **AdornerLayer not null** .

```
 var controls = _frameworkElementProvider.GetUIElements(Content);
 var controlsWithAddorner = new List<FrameworkElement>();

 foreach (var control in controls) {
    var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(control);
    if (adornerLayer != null) {
       controlsWithAddorner.Add(control);
    }
 }
```

The collection **controlsWithAddorner** contains all my 3 controls.

*The method* `GetUIElements(FrameworkElement parent)` *returns an* `IEnumerable<FrameworkElement>` *in which are all controls within a **Panel**.*

I have such a functionality: 
**Refresh Form Designer**. Which recreates the xaml for that Form.

After that **Refresh** is done, I check the list of controls for AdornerLayer. For all controls the AdornerLayer is null.

The problem is here, I cannot understand where AdornerLayer (s) are lost? 
Should I take care To add them forr each UIElement when I Refresh the Designer of the Form?

Please advice me with some suggestions.

### Thank you!

---

**EDIT:**
I'll show all the solution if other will encounter such problems :)

The mission is: When there is a SelectedControl in designer, keep it selected even a RefreshDesigner is done.

[image]

**RefreshDesigner** functionality recreates the xaml for the whole form.

```
// Refresh the Designer
private void RefreshDesigner() {    
    Content = _xamlProvider.ParseXaml(_xaml.ToString());

    //Here was the Problem. All visual child elements of the Content wa not updated after xaml recreation.
    //By including that call -> solved the problem
    Content.UpdateLayout();
}
```

**Firstly**: The xaml of the Form is Updated by using the `ParseXaml()` method from `XamlProvider`

```
// in XamlProvider class 
public Panel ParseXaml(string xaml) {
    var regex = new Regex("<Grid ");
    const int first = 1;
    xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, @"xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""", string.Empty);
    xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, @"xml:space=""preserve""", string.Empty);

    //...

    xaml = Regex.Replace(xaml, "<BindingGroup .*/>", string.Empty);

    var content = (Panel)XamlReader.Parse(xaml);
    return content;
}
```

**Secondly:** `Content.UpdateLayout();`
Ensures that all visual child elements of this element are properly updated for layout.
[MSDN Official source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx)

After that, All elements have AdornelLayer not Null and I'm able to set the Adorner Border for preciosly selected control in designer.

Comment: Normally this should work. I assume that somehow the frameworkelements are cloned or detached from the VisualTree. Can you try to get the AdornerLayer for one control directly, e.g. var adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(yourButton);   Does this work?

Comment: @SvenG, thank you. The actual given Code works ok for all controls in my Panel, but I've tried to get AdornerLayer for concrete control because I want to use an Adorner Border to show visually the **"SelectedControl"** in designer, but it returns NULL. I found where is the problem. *After the Form is Refreshed*, I should call `Content.UpdateLayout();` to Ensures that all visual child elements of the Content were properly updated for layout.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039066/getadornerlayer-mysteriously-returning-null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the Form is Refreshed, call `Content.UpdateLayout();` to Ensures that all visual child elements of the Content were properly updated for layout. [MSDN official](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx)