# How to create custom Adorner ContentControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, contentcontrol, adorner

I'm trying to create an adorner layer in which I can place, e.g., notifications. I want to make it general and XAML-authored as much as possible, so I made new a `ContentControl`, called `AdornerContentControl`, used like this:

```
<AdornerDecorator Grid.Row="1" Name="RichTextBoxAdornerDecorator">
    <loc:AdornerContentControl x:Name="TestAdorner">
        <loc:AdornerContentControl.Decorator>
            <Button Width="100" Height="100">ZZZ</Button>
        </loc:AdornerContentControl.Decorator>
        <RichTextBox>
            <!-- some more stuff... -->
        </RichTextBox>
    </loc:AdornerContentControl>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

This is the code:

```
public class AdornerContentControl : ContentControl {
    private SimpleAdorner _adorner;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DecoratorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Decorator", typeof (Control), typeof (AdornerContentControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(Control),
                OnDecoratorPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnDecoratorPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { /*...*/ }

        protected override void OnInitialized(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInitialized(e);
            try { _adorner = new SimpleAdorner((UIElement)Content, Decorator); }
            catch (NullReferenceException) { }
        }

        public Control Decorator
        {
            get { return (Control) GetValue(DecoratorProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DecoratorProperty, value); }
        }
}

public class SimpleAdorner : Adorner{
    public SimpleAdorner([NotNull] UIElement adornedElement, Control content) : base(adornedElement)
    {
        _visuals = new VisualCollection(this);
        _adornerLayer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(adornedElement);

        if (content == null) return;

        _visuals.Add(_contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter()
        {
            Content = content
        });

        _adornerLayer.Add(this);
    }
}
```

But `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(adornedElement)` always returns `null` (the `SimpleAdorner` is constructed in `OnInitialized`).

[Should I explicitly create `AdornerDecorator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039066/getadornerlayer-mysteriously-returning-null) ?

[Am I supposed to call `Content.UpdateLayout` somewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17294422/adornerlayer-getadornerlayer-return-null-for-all-controls-in-a-panel) ?

Comment: Perhaps you could explain exactly what you are trying to do *with words*, rather than code?

Comment: @Sheridan, Edited: I'm trying to create an adorner layer in which I can place, e.g., notifications. I want to make it general and XAML-authored as much as possible.

Comment: It sounds like you have picked the wrong tool for the job. The `Adorner` class is great at doing what it is supposed to do, but that comes with a small price... it is not as straight forward to use as other controls. So why go to all the trouble of using an `Adorner`, when you *aren't* using it according to its designed use and you could use a `Popup` control in it's place, but just a whole lot easier?

Comment: @Tal I wonder if its not that you are donig this via the constructors... Perhaps you are attempting to access the level before it has been created.

Comment: @Sheridan - I need some kind of "Toast" message. `Popup` isn't suitable here, I need the message (together with all its inner content - buttons, selectors, ...) to be embedded in GUI as a layer above the "toastee" element

Comment: @Andrew, I tried to postpone its creation as much as I could. I even tried to run this code from user-action event. Only when I wrapped the content (the `RichTextBox` in my example) in an `AdornerDecorator` and used `AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(myRichTextBox)` (on my `RichTextBox`) it worked. But this solution forces me to "inject" an `AdornerDecorator` between my content and my `adornedElement`, which feels messy... I was thinking that every element usually has an adorner layer by default, but maybe I'm wrong...